# How to layout like less-or-equal-to in Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter

[image]

`Now` layout code as below:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Text(
          'Text',
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      width: 100,
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Text('Fixed Widget'),
    ),
  ],
),
```

How to layout to achieve the `Expected` result, like iOS's `lessOrEqualTo`? Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `Expanded` with `Flexible`, like:

Code:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Text(
          'TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText',
           overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      width: 100,
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Text('Fixed Widget'),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code bellow:

```
            Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 100
              ),
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text(
                'How to layout to achieve the Expected result, like iOS lessOrEqualTo? Thanks for any tips.',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 100,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text('Fixed Widget'),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Flexible Widget like this:

```
child: Container(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text(
                  'Text 123456 2345678 56789 34567 34567 34567 23456 34524',
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Text('Fixed Widget'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```